# Electron-packager not setting icons

Tags: javascript, electron, electron-packager

There are lots of questions relating to setting icons using `electron-packager` but none of the answers have worked for me – maybe the answers are out of date or not clear – but I need to ask again.

I am building on OSX for OSX & Windows. I've tried at least 20 variations on specifying the icon for `electron-packager` (the full cmd set is below). I've tried referencing icons withing the app folder (app/assets/WIN_logo.icns) as well as in an "icons" folder at the project root (icons/assets/WIN_logo.icns); I've tried using quotation marks, leaving off the extension and other stuff I can't even recall.

So please, can someone tell me, given the directory structure below, how I specify the icon for `electron-packager` to use.

```
-icon=assets/WIN_logo.icns
-icon=assets/WIN_logo.ico
```

[image]

```
  "package-mac": "electron-packager . --overwrite --tmpdir=false --platform=darwin --arch=x64  --prune=true --out=release-builds -icon=assets/WIN_logo.icns",
  "package-win": "electron-packager . --overwrite --tmpdir=false --platform=win32 --arch=ia32 --asar=true  --prune=true --out=release-builds -icon=assets/WIN_logo.ico"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `-icon=assets/...` to `--icon=./assets/...`

The icon argument should have two hyphens at the start and the path should start with `./`.

Comment: Even with an updated path, I'm still not getting the icon coming through building for mac

Comment: I tried this command for my application and ended up with the error `Packaging app for platform win32 x64 using electron v4.0.5
rcedit.exe failed with exit code 1. Cannot open icon file '.'
Fatal error: Unable to set icon`

Comment: @JacobNelson I'll need a bit more detail than that to fix your problem. Can you post a seperate question

Answer (score 5):

**For mac**

1/ verify that the name of the icon is icon.icns 
2/ verify that the icon size is at least 512x512px
3/ change --out=release-builds by --out=build

**For windows**

1/ verify that the name of the icon is icon.ico 
2/ verify that the icon size is at least 256x256px
3/ change --out=release-builds by --out=build

*source : https://www.electron.build/icons*

these steps works for me.

Answer (score 0):

**[1] Icon path:** The icon path is not relative to the project directory, but to the current location. *(For me, the problem was that I assumed the former, as I thought it made sense with less redundancy.)* In any case, one has to run either:

```
electron-packager projectDirPath outputName ... --icon=projectDirPath/iconPath/icon.png
```

Or if you are in the project directory:

```
electron-packager . outputName ... --icon=iconPath/icon.png
```

**[2] Icon format:** For macOS, both icon.png and icon.icns is accepted. For Windows, both icon.png and icon.ico is accepted.

**[3] Icon size:** For macOS, the dimensions must be at least 512x512px. For Windows, the dimensions must be at least 256x256px.